# How to rename an output dataset within a function with R?

Tags: r

I made a function which its outputs are three different datasets in `.csv` format, but, I'll like that the name of the original dataset appears in the name of the output dataset.

For example:

If the name of the original dataset is "microbial_mat1", I'll like that output was "microbial_mat1_output1.csv", because I only get "_output1.csv".

Is there a way to do this?

My function looks like the following code:

```
myFunction <- function(original_dataset, 
                       parameter1, 
                       parameter2 = TRUE){
  a long bunch of code

  if(parameter2){
    write.csv(dataset_temporal, "_output.csv")
  } else{
    print("No parameter2")
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to extract the object name.  One option is to use `deparse/substitute` at the top of the function on the original_dataset and use that (nm1) with `paste` to create the file name

```
 myFunction <- function(original_dataset, 
                   parameter1, 
                   parameter2 = TRUE){

  nm1 <- deparse(substitute(original_dataset))
 ...
 ...

 if(parameter2){
    write.csv(dataset_temporal,  paste0(nm1, "_output.csv"))
    } else{
    print("No parameter2")
   }
```